# SQLalchemy throwing a data conversion error whereas pgadmin has no trouble?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I initially altered my tables in PGadmin4, just going through some code refactoring where i wanted to instead of  having my select statements in sql files to run on sqltools to do it through sqlalchemy instead.

The main problem i have run into, is that from my believe that it doesn't run multiple statements. So instead of having one file to do with my products table, I have split it into two seperate files instead.

file 00 :

```
ALTER TABLE public.dim_products
ADD COLUMN weight_class varchar(20);

UPDATE public.dim_products
SET removed =
CASE
    WHEN removed = 'Removed' THEN FALSE
        WHEN removed = 'Still_avaliable' THEN TRUE
END,
product_price = REPLACE(product_price, '£', ''),
weight = REPLACE(weight, 'kg', '');

ALTER TABLE public.dim_products
RENAME COLUMN removed to still_available;`

UPDATE public.dim_products
SET weight_class =
CASE
    WHEN weight::float < 2 THEN 'Light'
    WHEN weight::float >= 2 AND weight::float < 41 THEN 'Mid_Sized'
    WHEN weight::float >= 41 AND weight::float < 141 THEN 'HEAVY'WHEN weight::float >= 141 THEN 'Truck_Required'
END;

ALTER TABLE public.dim_products
RENAME COLUMN product_price to product_price_in_£;

ALTER TABLE public.dim_products
RENAME COLUMN weight to weight_in_kg;
```

and file 01 would be:

```
ALTER TABLE public.dim_productsALTER COLUMN product_price_in_£ TYPE FLOAT USING product_price_in_£::float,ALTER COLUMN weight_in_kg TYPE FLOAT USING weight_in_kg::float,
ALTER COLUMN "EAN" TYPE VARCHAR(14) USING "EAN"::varchar(14),
ALTER COLUMN product_code TYPE VARCHAR(14) USING product_code::varchar(14),
ALTER COLUMN date_added TYPE DATE USING date_added::date,
ALTER COLUMN uuid TYPE UUID USING uuid::uuid,
ALTER COLUMN still_available TYPE BOOL using still_available::bool,
ALTER COLUMN weight_class TYPE VARCHAR(20) USING weight_class::varchar(20),
ADD PRIMARY KEY (product_code);`
```

However the error that i keep getting on sqlalchemy is

```
`sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type double precision: "£3.00"`
```

So essisentially what i'm thinking is that it skips a few of the above statements went excuting due to if i was running this one giant script in pgadmin4 it would run without any problems so its definetly skipping the replace function. From what i've read on previous posts, i've opted to use begin() method of the connector due to it establishing a database connection and also transactioning those statements that change the structure, hence tried to split that file into two with the first part setting up the structure and the second part changing the column types but i still get this same data error. So essentially i am stumped

Here is my main method:

```
def main():
 #bunch of tables i'm initialising from scraping data from various places
    user_table_init()
    card_details_table_init()
    store_details_init()
    datetime_table_init()
    product_details_init()
    order_table_init()
    
    database_engine = database_utils.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:USERNAME@localhost:5432/Sale_Data')
    
with database_engine.begin() as con:
        for file in os.listdir('Database-structure'): #directory with all my sql files
            if file.endswith(".sql"):
                with open(os.path.join('Database-structure', file)) as alter_statements_sql:
                    query = text(alter_statements_sql.read()) #some files have multiple statements
                    
                    print(file)
                    con.execute(query) #read somewhere i can use Multi set that to true for multistatements except i think thats a function on mysql and not postgres
                    print('done')
                    
                    
        for file in os.listdir('Database-structure\Database-schema'):
            if file.endswith(".sql"):
                with open(os.path.join('Database-structure\Database-schema', file)) as relationships_statements_sql:
                    query = text(relationships_statements_sql.read())
                    con.execute(query)
```

**Summary**: when running same statements on PGAdmin there is no problem but when run on sqlalchemy there is a data conversion problem which from my understanding can be down to Postgres SQLAlchemy not allowing multiple statements from one sql file to be run.

Comment: I tried a similar pair of scripts and did not reproduce the error: all statements were executed.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yeah it seems to work just fine but when have the file and try to excute it with sqlalchemy connection object. It comes up with that error message which suggests to me that sqlalchemy doesnt allow a sql file with multiple statements and just excepts one statement per file. Because when it reads file 0, it doesn't include the replacing £ by space because later on theres a data error warning. So i think if i want to reproduce using sqlalchemy i'll need to split the statements into seperate files

Comment: @snakecharmerb thats strange can i ask how you ran it compared to my implementation of it, i'll edit my question to include it

Comment: @snakecharmerb noticed i already have the main there, is there a different implementation that you've done compared to mine?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/a9dhiV8e

Comment: @snakecharmerb I believe its the way its built it only takes 1 statement at a time when using the psycog2 dialect whereas sqllite and others have support for multiline statements so i think essentiially what i'll have to do is split it into smaller setup files. Question from a hiring stance point will  it be better to see the implementation on sqltools with their respective files or broken down files but it can be done programatically. down side of option 1 it doesnt display much wheras option 2 you'll lose a lot on readability

Comment: 1) This `ALTER TABLE public.dim_productsALTER COLUMN product_price_in_£ ...` is not going to work. Not sure if that is a typo/cut and paste error or how the statements are actually mashed together in the file. 2) The error `invalid input syntax for type double precision: "£3.00"` indicates that this `product_price = REPLACE(product_price, '£', ''),` is not doing what you think it is and that this `... USING product_price_in_£::float` is the source of the error. It would also imply that 1) is actually a typo. 3) Look at the Postgres log and see what is actually hitting the database.